# Why is `rm` seemingly ignoring escapes?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, rm

I'm trying to `rm` a directory and its contents, however for whatever reason `rm` is ignoring escape characters.

In this example, I'm trying to remove the folder `Team Fortress 2` from `~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common`:

```
[redacted@host common]$ rm -r Team\ Fortress\ 2/
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘Team’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘Fortress’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘2/’: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried wrapping the directory name in quotes:

```
[redacted@host common]$ rm -r 'Team\ Fortress\ 2/'
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘Team\\’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘Fortress\\’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/rm: cannot remove ‘2/’: No such file or directory
```

Here's the output from `rm --version`:

```
rm (GNU coreutils) 8.21
...
```

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first guess would be that *rm* is a poorly defined function or script, e.g., something like

```
rm()
{
    /usr/bin/rm -i $1
}
```

To find out, execute this command:

```
type rm
```

If I'm wrong, it will say:

```
rm is /usr/bin/rm
```

If I'm right, it will tell you exactly how *rm* has been redefined.

Comment: Thanks - I had a function for `rm` that I had since removed, but I was running the command here in a tmux session that was still using my old `.bashrc`. `rm` is now working again.